# Calculate UTC time when I know the timezone and the time in that timezone

Tags: php

I have a legacy system that does some magic with time.

I can set the timezone(ex: `Europe/Bucharest` somewhere in the legacy system. An admin can enter a time somewhere in the backend **BUT** it will always be UTC time.

Once the time is saved in the database it will take into account the above set timezone. So even though the admin entered say 10 PM the time in the database will be 7 PM(yes, it's a little stupid, I agree).

If I was to take the time directly from the database, which I am doing, the time won't be what the admin actually entered, it will be adjusted to the timezone.

Long story short: How can I calculate the correct UTC time if I know the timezone and the time in that timezone? Ex: go from 7 PM to 10 PM, when I know that the timezone is `Europe/Bucharest`. I want to do this in a non-hackish way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is your system stores the dates as UTC (which is a good idea if the system potentially needs to be accessed by users from different timezones). I also understand that when Admin enters date it's get converted to UTC before saving in DB (which is also quite sensible approach)? And now you need to be able to read from database and present the date in the local time:

```
$database_time = '2017-09-02T21:00:00'; 
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $database_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$your_tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$date_obj->setTimeZone($your_tz);
var_dump($date_obj);
```

If you need to do the opposite (saving the local time as UTC in DB or just show UTC time) then:

```
$local_time = '2017-09-02T23:00:00'; 
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $database_time, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$db_tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
var_dump($date_obj);
```

If however the database stores data in known timezone, and you simply need to convert that time to UTC it's a matter of:

```
$database_time = '2017-09-02T21:00:00'; 
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $database_time, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$date_obj->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date_obj->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Comment: The real beauty of `createFromFormat()` is that it allows the entire thing to be a one-liner: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $database_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` :)

Comment: You were close, not with the code, with the understanding. The time stored in the database is in the current timezone(keeping up with the example, `Europe/Bucharest`).

Comment: OK, in this case the second example from my answer still will do, you just need to assume that $local_time is in fact the time you are trying to convert to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I guess...

(if anybody wants to add or correct me, really, please do).

```
$database_time = '2017-09-02T21:00:00';

$diff = date('Z', strtotime($database_time)) / 3600; // to get the diff in hours, by default it's in seconds

$UTC_time = (new DateTime($database_time))->modify("+ $diff hour");

$UTC_time->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: @Jarek.D's answer is technically better.

Comment: Agreed, much better answer.